# Separate Specific String in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I have dataframe

```
company = pd.DataFrame({'coid': [1,2,3],
                        'coname': ['BRIGHT SUNLtd','TrustCo. New Era','PteTreasury']})
```

I want to separate Ltd, Co., and Pte from the text in coname, so the result will be like this:

```
coid coname
1    BRIGHT SUN Ltd
2    Trust Co. New Era
3    Pte Treasury
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a **replacement dictionary**, which is quite useful if you should need to add more replacements in the future:

#### Code:

```
company = pd.DataFrame({'coid': [1,2,3],
                        'coname': ['BRIGHT SUNLtd','TrustCo. New Era','PteTreasury']})

replacements = {'Ltd':' Ltd', 
                'Co.':' Co.', 
                'Pte':'Pte '}

company["coname"].replace(replacements, regex=True, inplace=True)

print(company)
```

#### Output:

```
   coid             coname
0     1     BRIGHT SUN Ltd
1     2  Trust Co. New Era
2     3       Pte Treasury
```

Comment: Just a note on a few drawbacks of this solution, replace with a dictionary is costly (it runs a full replace for each key/value pair, so if you have a large dictionary this is inefficient), the order of the values in the dictionary matter (you have to be sure not to use a pattern that can be matched by a further key), and finally this won't handle already existing spaces ('ABC Co.' will become 'ABC  Co.' with 2 spaces)

Comment: The replacement dictionary makes this solution easy to read, easy to maintain, easy to update, and easy to understand.  The "already existing space" issue could in theory be eliminated with a better dictionary, eg. `"SUNLtd":"SUN Ltd"` You just need to choose a suitable replacement to account for the data in hand.

Comment: I see your point, but you can use a list of terms to replace and a regex for the same maintainability and keeping efficiency. In any case your solution is probably fine for 3 items, but it's important to be aware of the limitations of `replace` IMO ;)

Comment: Thanks mozway - as always - I appreciate your feedback.

Comment: I updated my answer to demonstrate how this could work with a regex, but I admit the code is more complex ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex with lookarounds:

```
company['coname'] = company['coname'].str.replace(r'(?<=\S)(?=Ltd\b|Co\b)|(?<=Pte)(?=\S)', ' ', regex=True)
```

Output:

```
   coid             coname
0     1     BRIGHT SUN Ltd
1     2  Trust Co. New Era
2     3       Pte Treasury
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UwXKw6/1)

##### from a list of terms to replace:

```
space_before = ['Ltd', 'Co']
space_after  = ['Pte']

import re

before = "|".join(re.escape(x)+r"\b" for x in space_before)
after = '|'.join(f'(?<={x})' for x in space_after)
pattern = fr'(?<=\S)(?={before})|(?:{after})(?=\S)'
# '(?<=\\S)(?=Ltd\\b|Co\\b)|(?:(?<=Pte))(?=\\S)'

company['coname'] = company['coname'].str.replace(pattern, ' ', regex=True)
```

Comment: You weren't lying when you said the code was more complex - haha. Thanks for updating. I can see now where you are coming from... will take me a few days to digest though :)

Comment: @ScottC "*I can see now where you are coming from*" -> not sure what this means, nor if this is true :p

Comment: My only question is "why is `str.replace` better than `replace`"?

Comment: `replace` would be roughly equivalent to running `str.replace` as many times as you have a key to replace

Answer (score 1):

If there are only three cases that you have shown in your question, you can simply use `.replace()` to replace an original one with the one with a preceding space.

for example:

```
company['coname'] = company['coname'].str.replace('Ltd', ' Ltd')
company['coname'] = company['coname'].str.replace('Co.', ' Co.')
company['coname'] = company['coname'].str.replace('Treasury', ' Treasury')
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
company['coname'] = company['coname'].str.replace(r'(?i)(Ltd|Co\.|Pte)', r' \1 ', regex=True).str.strip()
```

Regex description
https://regex101.com/r/c26fT6/1

```
0        BRIGHT SUN Ltd
1    Trust Co.  New Era
2          Pte Treasury
Name: coname, dtype: object
```

Comment: seems regex is more complicated, now are created double spaces. Here in `Co.  New`

Comment: `company['coname']=company['coname'].str.replace(r'(?i)(\S)(Ltd|Co.|Pte)|(Ltd|Co.|Pte)(\S)', r'\1\3 \2\4', regex=True)` removes the extra spaces